# fadeout of background image changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

by not using `background` like other for background image 
I am using this kind of style
HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
    <img id="bgChange" src="image/image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg > div {
  position: absolute ; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

and use a simple way to change image change the `src` 
JavaScript:

```
var imageRotating = document.getElementById("bgChange");
var i = 0;
setInterval(function imageRotator() {
    imageRotating.setAttribute("src", "image/image" + ++i + ".jpg");
    if (i == 3) { i = -1; }
}, 5000);
```

what I want to ask is :
using JQuery how to add `.fadeOut()` inside the script? I am beginner to JQuery so I hope I can have a bit detail answer.

Comment: Ok! So What fades out here. And is there anything that fades in simultaneously?

Comment: I want the background change slowly just like slideshow

Comment: @KashamaShinn You need to use two img elements then, search for crossfade images. As a side note this CSS rule `#bg > div` doesn't target anything in your posted HTML markup

Comment: Since you only have three elements, I would simply create three images and hide the 2nd and 3rd until it is time to switch, then fade out one and fade in the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it

HTML

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="image/image1.jpg" class="shown" />
    <img src="image/image2.jpg" />
    <img src="image/image3.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#bg img.shown{
    display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

setInterval(function imageRotator() {
        $("#bg img.shown").fadeOut("slow", function(){ $(this).removeClass("shown"); });

```
    if ($("#bg img.shown").next("img").length > 0) // if there is an image after this one
    { 
        $("#bg img.shown").next("img").fadeIn("slow", function(){ $(this).addClass("shown"); });
    }
    else
    {
        $("#bg img:first-child").fadeIn("slow", function(){ $(this).addClass("shown"); });
    }
}, 2000);
```

EDIT:

Made a few small fixes. Here's a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/k40rcpbf/

You had some CSS rules to govern divs within `#bg` but your HTML didn't have any

Comment: background image stuck at first image. It is not change

Comment: agree that work...however, when I apply it on my web ... nothing change at all...

could it be because I using something call page wrap

`#page-wrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
   opacity :0.8;
}`

Comment: @KashamaShinn you forgot to add jquery to that fiddle (from the dropdown on the left), here's the updated one http://jsfiddle.net/k40rcpbf/3/ note you have the same image there for 1 and 3 so there is a sort of flash between the changes

Comment: you already marked my post as the answer, but you can upvote it if you like =)

Answer (score 0):

After setInterval

```
$( "#bgChange" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
  // ...
});
```

Edit: I explain.

You should have a 2 or more images.Code is not tested.Source code just to give you ideas.

```
<div id='phototab'>
<img class=active_img src="picture1.png">
<img src="picture2.png">
</div>
<script>
function changePhoto(){
 var current_img=$("#phototab .active_img");
 var next_img=curent_img.next();
    curent_img.fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      current_img.removeClass('active_img');
      next_img.addClass('active_img');
    });
}
setInterval('changePhoto()', 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: I dont really get it.

Comment: Please try explaining what you have answered.